# Namespace aliases in "stdafx.h"?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have several reasonably long namespaces such as "bridge_common_functionality".  It's not a major problem to use them in full e.g.

```
bridge_common_functionality::PrettyPrint(fout, print_cards, i_hands, v_formatted, input_deal_no);
```

But this program is Windows-specific, so I was wondering what are the pros and cons of creating short global aliases in "stdafx.h"?

```
namespace bridge_common_functionality {
} // namespace bridge_common_functionality
namespace bcf = bridge_common_functionality;
```

Obviously, one would only consider this once the namespaces are finalized.

TIA.

Comment: The pro is that the alias is active in any source code file in your project.  The con is that the alias is active in any source code file in your project.

Comment: I could selectively expose the aliases but is there any real downside to them being active in every source code file?